# Hosting an asp.net website in a windows 10 virtual machine

Tags: asp.net, windows, hosting

Is it possible and an acceptable solution to use a machine with windows os (not windows server) to host an asp.net website? Is all I need IIS regardless the os?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you know how to manage the server, you can always use your own server. Or you can also find shared hosting, it will be easier and you don't need ability to manage the server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. if your working with asp.net all you need is IIS witch is only integrated with Windows platforms. on the other hand if you're working with asp.net core it does not require IIS and can also be deployed to linux platforms.